# How can I list channel entries with same relationship to another channel?

Tags: channel-entries, relationships, ee3, related-entries, parent

I have two channels, Destinations and Hotels

Within the Hotels channel, I have a relationship field called `hotel_destination`, which relates it to the destination channel.

Now, on the hotel entry page/template, I'm struggling in being able to list the other hotel entries that are also related to the same destination.

Example. If Hotel 1, Hotel 2 and Hotel 3 were all related to Destination 1, then on the Hotel 1 entry page, I'd like to be able to display a listing of Hotel 2 and Hotel 3, as they are also related to Destination 1. Likewise if I selected the Hotel 2 entry page, I'd want to see Hotel 1 and Hotel 3.

The ultimate aim is to have the 'sibling' hotels listed in a sidenav of sorts, so that users know which other hotels are in a given destination.

I read and played around with the Relationship field with no luck and hoped someone might point me in the right direction

Thanks

Comment: can you please post some of your code so that we can see how you are trying to go about displaying the info?

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that this example pulled right from the [relationships docs](https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/fieldtypes/relationships.html#accessing-siblings) will work for you:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="hotels"}
  {hotel_destination}
    {hotel_destination:siblings field="hotel_destination"}
      {hotel_destination:siblings:title}
    {/hotel_destination:siblings}
  {/hotel_destination}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```